# find the position of an element in a string vector in common lisp

Tags: vector, common-lisp

Returning the position of a element in a string and a numerical vector, and a character vector works using `position`

```
CL-USER> (position #\T  "ACGT")
3
CL-USER> (position 2  #(1 2 3 4))
1

CL-USER> (position #\A  #(#\A #\C #\G #\T))
0
```

The following for a string vector does not work. I assume this is because a string is itself a vector of characters. 
So, what can one use?

```
CL-USER> (position "A"  #("A" "C" "G" "T"))
NIL
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, [POSITION](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_pos_p.htm) tests the element using [EQL](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eql.htm), which is true about most sequence function that use tests, as per [CLHS 17.2.1](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/17_ba.htm). For vectors EQL compares by identity, not contents, and two strings "A" will usually be different, even if they look the same. To compare by contents you need to pass `:test #'equal` to POSITION. Or [string= or string-equal](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_stgeq_.htm), which are specialized for strings and will signal an error if one of the arguments is not a string. Also `string-equal` is case insensitive.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very comprehensive answer. Wrt to `string=` vs `string-equal`, I would just quote the page you referenced. I.e. "string-equal is just like string= except that differences in case are ignored; two characters are considered to be the same if char-equal is true of them."

Comment: I looked at the CLHS page for `POSITION`, but couldn't find any reference to the default value for `TEST`. Maybe you can provide a CLHS link that clarifies this? (or a link to the CLHS page that gives guidelines about usage of `EQL` in sequence functions). Thanks!

Comment: @MironBrezuleanu: I would also have to find a link for that. But generally Common Lisp uses EQL as default for all test functions of the sequence functions. If you need something else, most of them have a :test keyword parameter

Comment: @RainerJoswig - Thanks, I was curious about the nature of this information (i.e. this is what implementations commonly do versus this is what the spec explicitly says). For `POSITION`, it's a funny thing to leave unspecified - it means that to write portable code one would have to always supply a value for `:test`; so I was hoping that maybe this is specified, but in a less obvious way.

Comment: @MironBrezuleanu: see 'same' in the CLHS glossary: same adj. ... 2. (of objects if no predicate is implied by context) indistinguishable by eql. Note that eq might be capable of distinguishing some numbers and characters which eql cannot distinguish, but the nature of such, if any, is implementation-dependent. Since eq is used only rarely in this specification, eql is the default predicate when none is mentioned explicitly. ``The conses returned by two successive calls to cons are never the same.'' ...

Comment: @MironBrezuleanu: under EQL in the CLHS: ...eql is the same as eq, except that if the arguments are characters or numbers of the same type then their values are compared. Thus eql tells whether two objects are conceptually the same, whereas eq tells whether two objects are implementationally identical. It is for this reason that eql, not eq, is the default comparison predicate for operators that take sequences as arguments....

Comment: @MironBrezuleanu: in the seqence documentation in the CLHS: 17.2.1 ...If neither a :test nor a :test-not argument is supplied, it is as if a :test argument of #'eql was supplied....

Comment: @RainerJoswig: Great, so it's in the spec. I remember looking at the `EQL` page this morning, but it appears I didn't pay enough attention. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try `(position "A" #("A" "B" "C" "D") :test #'equal)`.